# Java Does Not Equal (!=) Not Working?

Tags: java

Here is my code snippet:

```
public void joinRoom(String room) throws MulticasterJoinException {
  String statusCheck = this.transmit("room", "join", room + "," + this.groupMax + "," + this.uniqueID);

  if (statusCheck != "success") {
    throw new MulticasterJoinException(statusCheck, this.PAppletRef);
  }
}
```

However for some reason, `if (statusCheck != "success")` is returning `false`, and thereby throwing the `MulticasterJoinException`.

Comment: Equals() vs ==. http://www.zparacha.com/java-string-comparison/

Comment: http://leepoint.net/notes-java/data/strings/12stringcomparison.html

Comment: SO should start detecting this question and answering it on its own.

Comment: Didn't see an answer to this question in the suggestions as I entered in the title, so I figured it was unique. Guess not...

Comment: @KublaiKhan, I ask this question (`String` equality) during interviews. It's not often someone can answer when == works and when it doesn't (and how to make it work again).

Answer (score 237, accepted):

```
if (!"success".equals(statusCheck))
```

Comment: note that how Peter uses !"success".equals(statusCheck) rather than !statusCheck.equals("success"). This way you can avoid NullPointerException if statusCheck is null.

Comment: I'd suggest you also take a look on "*.equalsIgnoreCase(string)", just to make sure everything is fine.

Answer (score 43):

`==` and `!=` work on object identity. While the two `String`s have the same value, they are actually two different objects.

use `!"success".equals(statusCheck)` instead.

Comment: This is better than the accepted answer because it gives explanation.

Answer (score 35):

Sure, you can use `equals` if you want to go along with the crowd, but if you really want to amaze your fellow programmers check for inequality like this:

```
if ("success" != statusCheck.intern())
```

[intern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern()) method is part of standard Java String API.

Comment: +1 from me. Although I'd prefer not to see this idiom in codebase that I have to maintain, it sure is useful to know what intern() is and how it works. (Using Google Guava's Interner makes this stuff more explicit)

Comment: Four years later I realize I should have said that I'd never use that in "real" code and I don't recommend anyone else do so either.  There's probably some edge case where interning a string provides a slight performance improvement but the point of my answer was to educate and amuse.

Comment: Even assuming someone reading the code knows what "Intern()" does, they'll still be confused at why it's there, because they'll be trying to figure out _why_ it was used.

Comment: @Tasgall, I agree - if there's ever a need for `intern()` then it's safe to say that the code should be well documented.

Answer (score 8):

do the one of these.

```
   if(!statusCheck.equals("success"))
    {
        //do something
    }

      or

    if(!"success".equals(statusCheck))
    {
        //do something
    }
```

Comment: what is the difference between those 2 conditions?

Comment: **Wrong!** Don't you ever do that! (I mean, the first one). Why? if `statusCheck==null`, then you gonna get NPE in your face. In the second example you only get false is statusCheck is null. @AlicanBalik

Answer (score 4):

Please use `!statusCheck.equals("success")` instead of `!=`.

[Here](http://www.ensta-paristech.fr/~diam/java/online/notes-java/data/expressions/22compareobjects.html) are more details.

Comment: Actually you both @anubhava and SubOP are **wrong**. Never put a `nullable` object first in an `equals(Object)` method if you can. Should be `!"success".equals(statusCheck)`. Otherwise you can get a NPE if `statusCheck == null`

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the method `equals()` when comparing a string, otherwise you're just comparing the object references to each other, so in your case you want:

```
if (!statusCheck.equals("success")) {
```

Comment: equals, not Equals.

Comment: even better is to check for `!"success".equals(statusCheck)` in case statusCheck is null, will not throw a `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 2):

you can use equals() method to statisfy your demands. == in java programming language has a different meaning!