# Initialization fails, setter with if statement

Tags: java

```
public class Person{
    private String email;

    public Person() throws Exception {
        setEmail("info@yourmail.com");
    }

    public Person(String email) throws Exception {
        setEmail(email);
    }
  
  public void setEmail(String email) throws Exception {
        if (email.indexOf('@') == -1 || (email.substring(email.length() - 4) != ".com" && email.substring(email.length() - 3) != ".nz")) {
        throw new Exception("[ERROR] Email not correct");
    } else {
        this.email = email;
        }
    }
```

However, initialization always fails when I test it this way:

```
void init() {
        try{
            person = new Person("example@mail.com");
        }catch(Exception e) {
            fail("Parameterized constructor failed");
        }
    }
```

I am not able to figure why. Why is this happening?

Comment: Instead of `email.substring(email.length() - 4) != ".com"` you should use `email.endsWith(".com")`

Comment: Other comments are valid but also - do not use `==` or `!=` for string comparison: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8484699/2711811.

Comment: @xerx593 No, this is wrong. He wants to throw the exception if both is true (not ending with ".com" AND not ending with ".nz"). So, his logic is ok, his _tools_ are not.

Comment: ...yes, there is definitely more to fix, and not to forget: https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-1699

Comment: (email.substring(email.length() - 4) != ".com" && email.substring(email.length() - 3) != ".nz") is returning true mate